# Playframework 2.3.6 reactive-stocks-java8 template issue in eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, java-8, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I have a problem using Eclipse as IDE for the reactive-stocks-java8 template coming with typesafe-activator-1.2.10

Here are my steps:

## Install Eclipse Luna on my Mac.

Default JRE is 1.6, but I have the oracle JDK in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/ after installing with the standard method. I add this JRE to the alternate JRE of eclipse

## Install activator

I've downloaded typesafe-activator-1.2.10.zip, unzip it in a folder, add it to the path to have activator in the command line.

## Create the project

```
$activator new
  > reactive-stocks-java8
$cd reactive-stocks-java8/

$java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$activator
[reactive-stocks-java8] $eclipse with-source=true
```

## In eclipse

I import the project in the standard way (Import / Existing Project into Workspace)
in the java build path, The JRE is the 1.6. I change it to 1.8.0_25
I also have to change the java compiler

In my package explorer or the Problems view, no compilation error, great. Now I click on app/controller/Application.java to open it in the editor. In the editor, I've got some unresolved:

```
views.html.index cannot be resolved to a type
The type scala.collection.Seq cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

here are the answers from the community

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/v6ep7DmfH18